# How to retrieve identity ID when inserting a row in the db using linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

How to retrieve identity ID when inserting a row in the db using linq?

Answer (score 4):

If you've set the properties of that "ID" row to "Auto-Generated Value" = true and "Auto-Sync" to "OnInsert"

[image]

..... just read it after you've saved the changes using `.SubmitChanges()`. No special tricks or anything needed....

So in case of the NerdDinner sample:

```
using(NerdDinnerContext ctx = new NerdDinnerContext())
{
    Dinner upcoming = new Dinner();

    // set all properties for the dinner 
    upcoming.EventDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);

    ctx.Dinners.InsertOnSubmit(upcoming);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();

    int newDinnerID = upcoming.DinnerID;
}
```

Now "newDinnerID" should contain the newly added IDENTITY.

Marc

Comment: gratz on the sql-server silver badge Marc

Comment: Thanks, Remus! You're not far away from it yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL should automatically retrieve the identity of the inserted object, and update the field you mapped to the primary key accordingly - so long as the mapped PK property is marked as `[Column(IsDbGenerated=true)]`.